# Swing JFrame horizontal scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying make a graph using java swing which I'm new at. In my program I am getting some random numbers from text file based on which the graph will be created. I have been able to make the graph but I need to add a scroll bar to see the full graph, which is long enough to fit in the generated window.
Could anyone modify or suggest me a very simple so

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.*; // used to access the JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, and JScrollPane class
import java.awt.*; // used to access the Font class

public class NewLine {
   MyPanel panel;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
        SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");




 f.setResizable(true);
 f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 //panel=new MyPanel();  

        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color GRAPH_COLOR = Color.red;
    private static final Color GRID_COLOR = Color.gray;

    public MyPanel() {
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(this, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        //JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a JScrollPane Component");

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250,200);
    }


    void drawLines(Graphics g) {


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setColor(GRID_COLOR);


         for(int x =20 ; x <=1020; x +=25 ){
         g2d.drawLine(x, 70, x, 500);  // Y AXIS
         }
         for(int y =70 ; y <=500; y +=25 ){
         g2d.drawLine(20, y, 1020, y); // X axis
         }
         g2d.setColor(GRAPH_COLOR);

         int x = 20;

         int diff = 5;
                    try{    
                        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

                        String strLine;

                //Read File Line By Line
                int counter = 0;
                int prevPoint = 0;
                        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                  // Print the content on the console
                        //x +=5

                        if( counter == 0){
                        System.out.println (strLine);
                        //g2d.drawLine(x, 500-312, x +=15, Integer.parseInt(strLine));
                        }
                        counter ++;
                        g2d.drawLine(x , 500-prevPoint, x +=5, 500-Integer.parseInt(strLine));

                        prevPoint =  Integer.parseInt(strLine);

                }
                //Close the input stream
                        br.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ec){}




    }



    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        drawLines(g);
    }
}
```

The value of the text file is something like below,

360
334
327
313
312
302
301
294
292
289
283
287
278
282
275
277
274
273
273
268
273
266
273
266
270
267
267
....

Thanks in Advance.
Anupam.

Comment: Also I would like to know what is the best way to create graph in java swing. I tried jfreechart but for me it was hard to manipulate according to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
f.add(new MyPanel());
```

By

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(
        new MyPanel(), 
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
);
f.add(scroll);
```

And replace this

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250,200);
}
```

By this

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1020,500);
}
```

Tadaaa!
[image]

Comment: Hi Niels , 

Thanks a lot for your help. It surely shows the scroll bar and but I could not drag the scrollbar and I could not completely see the graph.

Comment: I can on my machine. If you make the window smaller, the scroll bars appear and become drag-able. Because there is a fault in your drawing routine, the bottom line is not drawn. But that's out of scope of this question (horizontal scrollbar does not appear).

Comment: And what happens when you make the Window smaller? Because in your screenshot, scrollbars aren't necessary because the graph already fits the window.

Comment: But in the above image the graph has some parts which could be seen if you drag the window. But that part is not visible as you cant drag the scrollbar

Comment: Also could you please mention the  fault in drawing routine? It will help me learn the things better

Comment: You should be using multiples of your grid size (25). So g2d.drawLine(x, 70, x, 500);  // Y AXIS becomes g2d.drawLine(x, 70, x, 495);  // Y AXIS. 495 - 70 == 17 * 25

Comment: Or just g2d.drawLine(x, 70, x, 17 * 25);  // Y AXIS

Answer (score 2):

1. This stuff, parsing the data, should be in the constructor:

   ```
   try{
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
       // ... etc.
   ```
2. The values for the graph should be stored in an array or collection that is declared as an attribute of the class.
3. Stored as a class attribute, the data can be used when calculating the preferred size, or painting.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
basically this is part of java serial port reading so  this data will not come from any text file instead it will come from a serial port from an arduino board, which means the data will keep coming as long as the device is attached to the serial port.

Comment: In that case, it needs a separate thread to read the data, and to pass that data into the model for the graph, then call for a `repaint()` - perhaps you'd also need to `revalidate()`. Post a [mcve] if you want to pursue this. Having said that, I note you have been led astray with the accepted answer. It should not be hard coding the width of the plot, which will (presumably) get larger over time (unless the code scales the X axis, which would make the scroll-pane redundant).